# Может быть – обособляется?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, вводные-слова

"Может быть(,) ты ответишь уже на вопрос?!"

Нужна ли запятая в данном примере? Действительно ли "может быть" здесь вводное слово, ведь оно синонимично слову "наверное", здесь же такого смысла нет совсем.

Answer (score 5):

*Может быть, ты ответишь уже на вопрос?!*

Запятая нужна. ***Может быть*** здесь является вводным сочетанием, одно из значений которого указано, например, в словаре Ефремовой:

> <...>
> 3. Употребляется как вводное словосочетание, смягчая категоричность вопроса или побуждения.

Источник: [GLOSUM](https://glosum.ru/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C). Здесь же приводятся и синонимы, среди которых есть ***надеюсь***.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш как всегда обстоятельный ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Я дополню ответ Александра.

**1. О значении**

Итак, в словаре Ефремовой мы видим: II част. 1. Употребляется при выражении неуверенного подтверждения. 2. Употребляется как вводное словосочетание, выражающее возможность, допустимость чего-либо или неуверенность в чём-либо: ***по-видимому, возможно, вероятно***. 3. Употребляется как вводное словосочетание, **смягчающее категоричность** вопроса или побуждения.

Действительно, можно обратить внимание на третье значение  – смягчение категоричности. Но все дело в том, что в нашем случае мы не смягчаем категоричность вопроса, а **усиливаем** интонационными средствами:

(1) Ты ответишь на вопрос? Обычная фраза.

(2) Может быть, ты ответишь уже на вопрос?  Предположение, допустимость.

(3) МОжет быть, // ты ответишь уже на вопрос?!   Не смягченная, а усиленная категоричность, требование ответа.  Но вводное слово по-прежнему выделено ударением, пауза сохраняется, ставится запятая.

**Как назвать это явление?**  Пока я могу предложить термин *антифразис*, но не уверена в этом (возможны и другие варианты).  ***Антифразис, антифраз*** — употребление слова в противоположном значении. Разновидность тропа, стилистический приём, заключающийся **в употреблении** слова или словосочетания в противоположном смысле.

**2. О переходе вводного слова в частицу**

Мне кажется, эта тема связана с заданным вопросом. Ведь вполне можно предположить, что  вводное слово изменяет значение, **переходит в частицу** и не обособляется, как, например, в следующих сочетаниях: СкажИ пожалуйста, какой храбрец! Конечно прАвда!

Но здесь меняется интонация и расстановка ударений, поэтому  нет обособления. К тому же значение частицы указано в словаре, а в нашем же случае этого нет.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon, за интересные рассуждения и термин *антифразис* (плюсик мой горит). Я согласен с тем, что данное предложение-вопрос – это требование, и знаки в конце это подчеркивают. Но безапелляционная категоричность просматривалась бы в варианте без вводного слова: ***Ты ответишь уже на вопрос?!*** И по моим ощущениям, эта начальная добавка всё-таки выступает в своем прямом смысле – хоть как-то сгладить этот напор. Пусть это не улавливается напрямую, на слух, но подсознательно мы прибегаем к такому приему.

Comment: Здравствуйте, Александр, приятно вас слышать. А давайте с вами  потом (может, завтра) обсудим эту тему подробнее. Сейчас у меня со временем не очень, а  выяснить хочется.  Оказывается, все всё по-разному понимают.

Comment: И еще по поводу пауз. Очень, очень часто мы не делаем их вокруг вводных слов, особенно после них в начале предложения и в таких экспрессивных случаях, как этот. Запятые же мы ставим чисто по синтаксическим соображениям.

Answer (score 2):

Комментарий

Александр, я теперь как робот, рассуждаю по шагам, чтобы не запутаться.  Попробуем?

Шаг 1 (1). **Обсуждаем вариант БЕЗ ВВОДНОГО СЛОВА**: «Ты ответишь уже на вопрос?!»  Без дополнительных структурных элементов (к примеру, слова «всё-таки») трудно выразить требование только с помощью интонации. Можно ли сказать, что структурный элемент  «может быть»  (или «все-таки») НЕОБХОДИМ для выражения требования?  Да или нет?

Шаг 1 (2). **Обсуждаем ВОЗМОЖНОСТИ заданного предложения:**  « Может быть, ты ответишь уже на вопрос?». Здесь возможна как спокойная интонация, так и требование. Значит, не меняя структуру, можно выразить требование одной интонацией?  Ну и восклицательным знаком. Да или нет?

Шаг 1 (3). Есть ли здесь **переносное противоположное значение** (ирония, антифразис или что-то другое)? Да или нет?

Таким образом, к вам **три вопроса** :)

**Об интонации**

Здесь я с вами согласна, у меня даже есть «своя теория» на эту тему, основанная на практике, на наблюдениях. Это теория «старшей интонации».

Наблюдая за простыми и сложными сочетаниями и предложениями, я пришла к выводу о том, что интонация может выразить структуру и смысловые отношения  только для **старшей конструкции** (например,  БСП). Простые же предложения (а также различные обороты) в составе сложного предложения утрачивают свою собственную интонацию и становятся **строительными элементами.**

**Вводные слова** обычно подчиняются этому факту и не требуют для себя отдельного фразового ударения.  Нельзя сказать, что они вовсе не выделяются ударением, но это **дополнительное ударение** для обозначения небольшой **произносительной паузы**.  И чем сложнее предложение, тем меньше «интонационного» внимания мы им уделяем.

Но в некоторых случаях им достается и полноценное фразовое  или силовое ударение. В приведенном предложении (при значении **требования**) возможно именно такое **силовое выделение**: МОжет быть, // ты ответишь уже на вопрос?!

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 1**
Обсуждаем 1(1). Я возражаю и считаю, что «да».

**Пояснение**
«*Ты ответишь на вопрос*?»  –  здесь сложно выразить категорическое требование интонацией,  если только убедительно зарычать :)

«*Ты **уже** ответишь на вопрос*?».  Для требования странный порядок слов, попробуем переставить.

«*Ты  ответишь **уже** на вопрос*?» Чтобы выразить требование,  здесь тоже придется  напрягать голосовые связки. И это понятно, ведь эта фраза может обозначать вполне  мирную ситуацию: так спрашивают студента, готов ли он отвечать.

И вот на помощь приходит ВОЛШЕБНОЕ СЛОВО «может», которое используется ИРОНИЧЕСКИ, в переносном смысле: это уже **не возможность, а необходимость (требование)**. При этом особо «требовательная»  интонация больше не нужна, что нас вполне устраивает. Мы часто используем эту фразу в обыденной речи,  причем говорим  достаточно спокойным тоном, но адресат понимает, что мы недовольны, чувствует иронию.

ВЫВОД:  Слово «может»  имеет **иронический** смысл  по отношению к значению «возможно». Тогда это **новое** значение (4) , а не  (3) со значением смягчения. Но так как  его нет пока в словаре,  то приходится считать его ТРОПОМ (переносом). А каким?

Comment: Попробуем. 1 (1) Нет, не необходим, требование можно выразить интонацией (!), тем более присутствует усиление "уже". 1 (2) Да, однозначно. 1 (3) Не знаю. Это вопрос к произносящему и воспринимающему. Я не вижу противоположн. значения. /// И об ударении. Если уж произносить так, как написано у вас в конце, то тем более ощущается предположение, "надежда", что ответ на вопрос всё-таки последует. Хотя, конечно, "МОжет быть" можно произнести с угрозой, тогда и возникнет этот самый антифразис...

Comment: Спасибо за ответы!  Кажется, метод хорошо работает, просто как рентген: вижу все ваши мысли :) Причина разногласий тоже ясна. Об этом в дополнении.

Comment: Вот! После дополнения у меня вырисовывается понимание того, что прямое или переносное значение определяется целиком интонацией, эмоциями и намерением говорящего. Так что, думаю, в нашем случае возможно как то, так и другое.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ваше мнение.